# CSS of image in activeadmin in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, activeadmin

For image of users I use Paperclip and for admin I use activeadmin. All is going fine but in activeadmin index page missing.png images are showing large. I want o set their height and width but doesn't find any solution how to set their css only for missing.png images.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is buggy, but the idea should work.

```
if model.image.present?
  image_tag model.image.url(:thumb)
else
  image_tag model.image.url(:thumb), class: 'missing'
end
```

Comment: You need to replace `...` with the symbol for your size.